# JS из HTML в PHP

Tags: php, javascript

```html
<td width="54px" valign="top">
    <ul>
        <li onClick="view_tab(first_tab)"></li>
        <li onClick="view_tab(second_tab)"></li>
        <li onClick="view_tab(third_tab)"></li>
        <li onClick="view_tab(fourth_tab)"></li>
        <li onClick="view_tab(fifth_tab)"></li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

Весь код:

```html
<?php
echo '
<!--
 Code: ES.^
 JS: BloomerWD
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <HEAD>
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <TITLE>srvmsg Test</TITLE>
  
  <STYLE>
   body { margin:50px; padding:0; }
   .mtitle {
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    width: 270px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
   .mtitlet {
    margin-left: 23px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
   }
   .mico {
    background: url("titico.png") no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
   }
   .mtitletext{
    margin-left: 23px; 
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #e9e7e7;
   }
   .mmain {
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
    width: 270px;
    min-height: 120px;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
   }
   .mmain ul {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    list-style: none;
   }
   .mmain ul li {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #0063db;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
   .mmain ul li:hover {
    background-color: #0063db;
   }
   .texts {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #ffffff;
    word-break: break-all;
   }
   .mmain table {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
   }


   #box #tab { display: none; }
   #box #tab:first-child { display: block; }
  </STYLE>
  <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
   view_tab = function(tab) {
   var box = document.getElementById("box"),
   childs = box.getElementsByTagName("*");
   for (var i=0; i < childs.length; i++) {
    if (childs[i].getAttribute("tab")){
     childs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    if (childs[i].getAttribute("tab") == tab) {
     childs[i].style.display = "block";
    }
   }
  }
  </SCRIPT> 
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
  <div class="mtitle">
   <div class="mtitlet">
    <div class="mico"><span class="mtitletext">Pranešimai</span></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mmain">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <td width="54px" valign="top">
     <ul>
      <li onClick="view_tab(first_tab)"></li>
      <li onClick="view_tab(second_tab)"></li>
      <li onClick="view_tab(third_tab)"></li>
      <li onClick="view_tab(fourth_tab)"></li>
      <li onClick="view_tab(fifth_tab)"></li>
     </ul>
    </td>
    <td width="196px" valign="top">
     <div class="texts" style="max-width: 196px;"">
      <div id="box">
       <span id="tab" tab="first_tab">
        2015/08/15 18:09:30
        </br></br>
        Lorem ipsum - tai fiktyvus tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsum tapo...
        </br></br>
        <span style="float: right;">Parašė: <span style="color: #00ff4e;">Hopper_Enr</span></span>
       </span>
       <span id="tab" tab="second_tab">
        2015/08/15 18:10:45
        </br></br>
        Lorem ipsum - tai fiktyvus tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsum tapo...
        </br></br>
        <span style="float: right;">Parašė: <span style="color: #00ff4e;">Armando_Vito</span></span>
       </span>
       <span id="tab" tab="third_tab">
        2015/08/15 18:12:10
        </br></br>
        Lorem ipsum - tai fiktyvus tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsum tapo...
        </br></br>
        <span style="float: right;">Parašė: <span style="color: #00ff4e;">Aivaras_Vercetti</span></span>
       </span>
       <span id="tab" tab="fourth_tab">
        2015/08/15 18:15:40
        </br></br>
        Lorem ipsum - tai fiktyvus tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsum tapo...
        </br></br>
        <span style="float: right;">Parašė: <span style="color: #00ff4e;">Torio_Takahashi</span></span>
       </span>
       <span id="tab" tab="fifth_tab">
        2015/08/15 07:19:10
        </br></br>
        Lorem ipsum - tai fiktyvus tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsum tapo...
        </br></br>
        <span style="float: right;">Parašė: <span style="color: #00ff4e;">Filibero_Lamberti</span></span>
       </span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </td>
   </table>
  </div>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
';
?>
```

Ошибка:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
>   in C:\<...>\test.php on line 105

В .php файле JS не работает из-за того что убрал из wiew_tab апострофы, если использовать апострофы - выдает ошибку, c кавычками не работает. В .html с апострофами код работает. Как исправить?

Comment: Напишите какая ошибка. Я так понял `<li onClick="view_tab('first_tab')"></li>` приводит к ошибке (с апострофами) ? И приведите php код до и после html разметки

Comment: Добавил весь код и ошибку в первое сообщение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам посоветую выводить html, просто разорвав php код и используя апострофы. Ведь одна из главных фишек php - встраивание в html.

```
<?php 
  //тут какой-то код
?>
<!--
    Code: ES.^
    JS: BloomerWD
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <HEAD>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <TITLE>srvmsg Test</TITLE>

        <STYLE>
            body { margin:50px; padding:0; }
            .mtitle {
                background-color: #2c2c2c;
                width: 270px;
                height: 40px;
                border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .mtitlet {
                margin-left: 23px;
                margin-top: 12px;
                line-height: 16px;
            }
            .mico {
                background: url("titico.png") no-repeat;
                width: 16px;
                height: 16px;
            }
            .mtitletext{
                margin-left: 23px; 
                font-family: Tahoma;
                font-size: 13px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #e9e7e7;
            }
            .mmain {
                background-color: #2f2f2f;
                width: 270px;
                min-height: 120px;
                border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
            }
            .mmain ul {
                margin:0; 
                padding:0;
                margin-left: 20px;
                padding-top: 20px;
                list-style: none;
            }
            .mmain ul li {
                margin-bottom: 6px;
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
                cursor: pointer;
                border: 2px solid #0063db;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
            .mmain ul li:hover {
                background-color: #0063db;
            }
            .texts {
                margin:0; 
                padding:0;
                padding-top: 20px;
                font-family: Tahoma;
                font-size: 11px;
                color: #ffffff;
                word-break: break-all;
            }
            .mmain table {
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }


            #box #tab { display: none; }
            #box #tab:first-child { display: block; }
        </STYLE>
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
            view_tab = function(tab) {
            var box = document.getElementById("box"),
            childs = box.getElementsByTagName("*");
            for (var i=0; i < childs.length; i++) {
                if (childs[i].getAttribute("tab")){
                    childs[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                if (childs[i].getAttribute("tab") == tab) {
                    childs[i].style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        }
        </SCRIPT> 
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <div class="mtitle">
            <div class="mtitlet">
                <div class="mico"><span class="mtitletext">Pranešimai</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mmain">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <td width="54px" valign="top">
                    <ul>
                        <li onClick="view_tab('first_tab')"></li>
                        <li onClick="view_tab('second_tab')"></li>
                        <li onClick="view_tab('third_tab')"></li>
                        <li onClick="view_tab('fourth_tab')"></li>
                        <li onClick="view_tab('fifth_tab')"></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td width="196px" valign="top">
                    <div class="texts" style="max-width: 196px;"">
                        <div id="box">
                            <span id="tab" tab="first_tab">
                                2015/08/15 18:09:30
                                </br></br>
                                Lorem ipsum - tai fiktyvus tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsum tapo...
                                </br></br>
                                <span style="float: right;">Parašė: <span style="color: #00ff4e;">Hopper_Enr</span></span>
                            </span>
                            <span id="tab" tab="second_tab">
                                2015/08/15 18:10:45
                                </br></br>
                                Lorem ipsum - tai fiktyvus tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsum tapo...
                                </br></br>
                                <span style="float: right;">Parašė: <span style="color: #00ff4e;">Armando_Vito</span></span>
                            </span>
                            <span id="tab" tab="third_tab">
                                2015/08/15 18:12:10
                                </br></br>
                                Lorem ipsum - tai fiktyvus tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsum tapo...
                                </br></br>
                                <span style="float: right;">Parašė: <span style="color: #00ff4e;">Aivaras_Vercetti</span></span>
                            </span>
                            <span id="tab" tab="fourth_tab">
                                2015/08/15 18:15:40
                                </br></br>
                                Lorem ipsum - tai fiktyvus tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsum tapo...
                                </br></br>
                                <span style="float: right;">Parašė: <span style="color: #00ff4e;">Torio_Takahashi</span></span>
                            </span>
                            <span id="tab" tab="fifth_tab">
                                2015/08/15 07:19:10
                                </br></br>
                                Lorem ipsum - tai fiktyvus tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsum tapo...
                                </br></br>
                                <span style="float: right;">Parašė: <span style="color: #00ff4e;">Filibero_Lamberti</span></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </table>
        </div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
<?php 
  //тут еще код
?>
```

Если такой вариант вас не устраивает, то можно использовать синтаксиси HEREDOC (или NOWDOC). Вот так

```
<?php 
  //тут какой-то код
$tmp = <<<"GGG"

<!--
    Code: ES.^
    JS: BloomerWD
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <HEAD>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <TITLE>srvmsg Test</TITLE>

        <STYLE>
            body { margin:50px; padding:0; }
            .mtitle {
                background-color: #2c2c2c;
                width: 270px;
                height: 40px;
                border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .mtitlet {
                margin-left: 23px;
                margin-top: 12px;
                line-height: 16px;
            }
            .mico {
                background: url("titico.png") no-repeat;
                width: 16px;
                height: 16px;
            }
            .mtitletext{
                margin-left: 23px; 
                font-family: Tahoma;
                font-size: 13px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #e9e7e7;
            }
            .mmain {
                background-color: #2f2f2f;
                width: 270px;
                min-height: 120px;
                border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
            }
            .mmain ul {
                margin:0; 
                padding:0;
                margin-left: 20px;
                padding-top: 20px;
                list-style: none;
            }
            .mmain ul li {
                margin-bottom: 6px;
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
                cursor: pointer;
                border: 2px solid #0063db;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
            .mmain ul li:hover {
                background-color: #0063db;
            }
            .texts {
                margin:0; 
                padding:0;
                padding-top: 20px;
                font-family: Tahoma;
                font-size: 11px;
                color: #ffffff;
                word-break: break-all;
            }
            .mmain table {
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }


            #box #tab { display: none; }
            #box #tab:first-child { display: block; }
        </STYLE>
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
            view_tab = function(tab) {
            var box = document.getElementById("box"),
            childs = box.getElementsByTagName("*");
            for (var i=0; i < childs.length; i++) {
                if (childs[i].getAttribute("tab")){
                    childs[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                if (childs[i].getAttribute("tab") == tab) {
                    childs[i].style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        }
        </SCRIPT> 
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <div class="mtitle">
            <div class="mtitlet">
                <div class="mico"><span class="mtitletext">Pranešimai</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mmain">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <td width="54px" valign="top">
                    <ul>
                        <li onClick="view_tab('first_tab')"></li>
                        <li onClick="view_tab('second_tab')"></li>
                        <li onClick="view_tab('third_tab')"></li>
                        <li onClick="view_tab('fourth_tab')"></li>
                        <li onClick="view_tab('fifth_tab')"></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td width="196px" valign="top">
                    <div class="texts" style="max-width: 196px;"">
                        <div id="box">
                            <span id="tab" tab="first_tab">
                                2015/08/15 18:09:30
                                </br></br>
                                Lorem ipsum - tai fiktyvus tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsum tapo...
                                </br></br>
                                <span style="float: right;">Parašė: <span style="color: #00ff4e;">Hopper_Enr</span></span>
                            </span>
                            <span id="tab" tab="second_tab">
                                2015/08/15 18:10:45
                                </br></br>
                                Lorem ipsum - tai fiktyvus tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsum tapo...
                                </br></br>
                                <span style="float: right;">Parašė: <span style="color: #00ff4e;">Armando_Vito</span></span>
                            </span>
                            <span id="tab" tab="third_tab">
                                2015/08/15 18:12:10
                                </br></br>
                                Lorem ipsum - tai fiktyvus tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsum tapo...
                                </br></br>
                                <span style="float: right;">Parašė: <span style="color: #00ff4e;">Aivaras_Vercetti</span></span>
                            </span>
                            <span id="tab" tab="fourth_tab">
                                2015/08/15 18:15:40
                                </br></br>
                                Lorem ipsum - tai fiktyvus tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsum tapo...
                                </br></br>
                                <span style="float: right;">Parašė: <span style="color: #00ff4e;">Torio_Takahashi</span></span>
                            </span>
                            <span id="tab" tab="fifth_tab">
                                2015/08/15 07:19:10
                                </br></br>
                                Lorem ipsum - tai fiktyvus tekstas naudojamas spaudos ir grafinio dizaino pasaulyje jau nuo XVI a. pradžios. Lorem Ipsum tapo...
                                </br></br>
                                <span style="float: right;">Parašė: <span style="color: #00ff4e;">Filibero_Lamberti</span></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </table>
        </div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
GGG;

echo $tmp; // вывод, можно было сразу echo <<<GGG ...
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что в этот html код планирую вмонтировать MySQL. Хочу извлечь информацию из базы данных, обработать ее и вывести информацию в таблицу. Поэтому скорее всего такой вариант мне не подойдет.
EDIT: План такой: задать запрос, извлечь информацию, переработать и вывести информацию при помощи цикла.

Comment: @ES. дополнил ответ. Хотя html лучше хранить в файлах, а не в базе.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я тут подумал... Скорее всего получиться сделать так как вы сказали, в 1 варианте. Ведь я могу в любом месте вставить php код, к примеру после <div class='texts' style='max-width: 196px;'">, таким образом, view_tab останется не тронутым, а в таблице такой проблемы по идеи быть не должно, имею ввиду ошибку с апострофами.

Comment: @ES. пожалуйста.